# How To Use Sweet alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

This Is My HTML Code
I Have Two Input Button That I Want To Show Sweet Alert When a user Clicks on any Button

```
<tr class="examples odd" id="UserId_1" role="row">
   <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
   <td>admin</td><td>Mohammad</td>
   <td>Farzin</td><td class="warning"><input type="button"
   value="Delete" class="sweet-5" id="btn_Delete1"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="examples even" id="UserId_5" role="row">
   <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
   <td>11</td><td>11</td>
   <td>11</td><td class="warning"><input type="button" value="Delete" class="sweet-5"
   id="btn_Delete5"></td>
</tr>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.querySelector('td.warning input').onclick = function () {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
        },
     function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
            }
        });
    };

});
```

Only The First Input Button Shows Sweet Alert, but 
when I click the second button nothing happens

Comment: I had a similar problem.In my case I was using same id for different buttons.Hope this might help someone with same problem.

Answer (score 13):

You were probably using [SweetAlert version 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) and your code applies to version 1.
This should work:

```js
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: 'Some text.',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No.'
}).then(() => {
  if (result.value) {
    // handle Confirm button click
  } else {
    // result.dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay', 'esc' or 'timer'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.8.2/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Source:
[Migration from Swal1 to Swal2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

Answer (score 4):

### Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', 'td.warning input', function () {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
      },
      function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
        } else {
          swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

### Check Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/5a6x3m36/5/

Comment: Thanks A Lot ,But It Does Not Work

Comment: @Mohammad Check Fiddle

Comment: @Hoja.M.A How can  I call php function after swal clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want sweet alert on click of any button then change your code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    Swal.fire({     
       type: 'success',
       title: 'Your work has been done',
       showConfirmButton: false,
       timer: 1500
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with sweet alert it is more easy for example i fave a link what i need is to call `onclick` function and make sure i included *sweetalser.css* and `sweetalert.min.js` i hope this will work for you

```
<a onclick="sweetAlert('Greetings', 'Hi', 'error');" class="" data-toggle="modal" href='#modale-id'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>Streams</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting the first element that matches `'td.warning input'` selector, that's why nothing happens to the second element.

Try `querySelectorAll('td.warning input')` method.
This returns an array and you can loop through the array to set Event Listeners.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload=function()

{

```
  swal({   title: "PopOutTitle",   text: "Your FIRST Name:",   type: "input",   showCancelButton: true, OnConfirm:school();  
         animation: "slide-from-top",     inputPlaceholder: name }, function(inputValue){   if (inputValue === false) return false;
         if (inputValue === "") { swal.showInputError("You need to write something!"); return false } 
           document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=inputValue || "Unknown";

});


 }
```

function school(){

```
  swal({   title: "PopOutTitle",   text: "Your last Name:",   type: "input",   showCancelButton: true,   
         animation: "slide-from-top",     inputPlaceholder: name }, function(inputValue){   if (inputValue === false) return false;
         if (inputValue === "") { swal.showInputError("You need to write something!"); return false } 
           document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=inputValue || "Unknown";

});**I want to show multiple swal popout so I want to call the school function when Ok Button is clicked. How can I do this?**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-danger').on("click", function(){
swal({
title: "Delete?",
text: "Please ensure and then confirm!",
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: !0,
confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
reverseButtons: !0
}).then(function (e) {
if (e.value === true) {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var id = $('.btn-danger').attr('data-id');
    var cur_row = this;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{url('/product_delete')}}/" + id,
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (results) {
    if (results.success === true)
    {
        swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
        setTimeout(function(){
                   location.reload()
                }, 2000);
    } 
    else
    {
        swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
    }
    }
    });
}
    });
  });
});
</script>

/* Add link in head section */
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The Below examples are taken from https://sweetalert2.github.io/.

Get the latest version of `sweetalter2` from here https://www.bootcdn.cn/limonte-sweetalert2/

### Displaying validation error

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.7.0/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
                
            Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Validation Error!!!',
                        text: 'Passwords Did not Match!',
                        footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
                        })
                    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Display custom html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Testing</title>
            <script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.7.0/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <script>
                Swal.fire({
              title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
              icon: 'info',
              html:
                'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
                '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
                'and other HTML tags',
              showCloseButton: true,
              showCancelButton: true,
              focusConfirm: false,
              confirmButtonText:
                '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
              confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
              cancelButtonText:
                '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
              cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})  
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```